# i am getting an error "project.html:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'transform' of undefined " for my clock project

Tags: javascript

All though I have searched stackoverflow for similar question but I am not able to find similarity between my code and the mistakes that those people were doing.

HTML:

```
    <div class="main-clock">
        <div class="hour"></div>
        <div class="minute"></div>
        <div class="second"></div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
setInterval(()=>{
let d=new Date();
seconds=d.getSeconds;
minutes=d.getMinutes;
hours=d.getHours;
hourRotation=(30*hours)+(minutes/2);
minuteRotation=(6*minutes)+((seconds/10));
secondRotation=(6*seconds);

document.getElementsByClassName("hour").style.transform = `rotate(${hourRotation}deg)`;
document.getElementsByClassName("minute").style.transform = `rotate(${minuteRotation}deg)`;
document.getElementsByClassName("second").style.transform = `rotate(${secondRotation}deg)`;
},1000);
```

Comment: Use `document.querySelector(.hour');` etc instead. `getElementsByClassName` returns a list of live nodes instead of single static node.

Comment: or you make ids and use getelementbyid. or you can use it like this document.getElementsByClassName("hour")[0].style.transform

Comment: @Andy What does that mean?

Comment: You can't apply a style to a whole nodelist. The other thing you could do I suppose is set the style on the first element of the nodelist: `getElementsByClassName('.hour')[0].style` but I think QS is the better choice.

Answer (score -1):

document.getElementsByClassName gets you an array. Like @Andy said you should careful about that and you can take [0] index if you want. So use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("hour")[0].style.transform
```

Another important point is that if your tags do not include the style attributes that you want to assing, it may occur the same error again careful about it.

Comment: Your answer is partially incorrect: the element does not need to contain a style attribute for the JS to set the value of a style property.

Comment: It's an _array-like_ nodelist. It doesn't support the majority of array methods. You can use `Array.from(nodelist)` or `[...nodelist]` to coerce it to a proper array.

Comment: i tried writing this and it still gave me error.also can you pls explain the statement about style attributes

Comment: The statement about style attributes is completely incorrect.